# Import tensorflow lite model into graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

Tensorflow: 2.2

I'd like to 'extend' a published tensorflow lite model with some additional post-processing on-GPU. Is it possible to load a tensorflow lite model into a tensorflow graph where those extra nodes can be added? It could then be re-exported as a new tensorflow lite model.

Comment: Re-importing an already converted `.tflite` model into a TensorFlow model is not officially supported. In many cases you should be able to also get the original TensorFlow model used for creating the `.tflite` model. Could you share which exact model you are interested in expanding?

Comment: I'm trying to extend the deeplabv3 model shown here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/segmentation/overview

Specifically, this one: https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/tflite/gpu/deeplabv3_257_mv_gpu.tflite

I can get a graphdef of the deeplabv3 model here: 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/deeplabv3_pascal_train_aug_2018_01_04.tar.gz'

which is mentioned in the article: https://averdones.github.io/real-time-semantic-image-segmentation-with-deeplab-in-tensorflow/

Alas, this model doesn't work because it's input tensor expects uint8.

Comment: When I define pre-processing operations, I always have to cast the results to uint8, and cast operations to uint8 are not supported by tflite.. This is why I was hoping to use the pre-built `.tflite` model. That model already accepts `float32` arguments as input. Short of that, I'd have to adjust the model myself and re-train it. A real pain.

Comment: See this notebook for tips on how to load the DeepLabV3's frozen graph into a TF session. You can't update the deeplabv3 graph but can add a subgraph that takes the output of the Deeplab model and do something more. Then you can export the whole graph as a SavedModel and convert it to a single TF Lite model.

https://github.com/sayakpaul/Adventures-in-TensorFlow-Lite/blob/master/DeepLabV3/DeepLab_TFLite_COCO.ipynb

Comment: Yes, I know how to do this, but There is a pre-processing step I'd like to add as well. This requires a cast operation which isn't currently supported by tflite. (cast to uint8). I was hoping I could perhaps 'pop-off' a couple operations from the front of DeepLabV3 since I think it does some uint8 to float conversion first. Cast to float is supported by tflite so it ought to work in that case.